# I do not understand why this function reverses the string

Tags: python, function, for-loop

This function requests a string input and reverses it. For some reason, I just cannot wrap my head around the logic behind it.

```
def reverse(s):
    new = ""
    for i in s:
        print(new)
        new = i + new
    return new
oldStr = input("String?")
newStr = reverse(oldStr)
print(newStr)
print(reverse("good bye"))
```

A friend suggested I print the variable new in the string which I added and it helped a little, but I just don't understand it.

Comment: the `"A"` should be an empty string `""`. The logic is that you are prepending the string elements with each iteration which results in a reversed string

Comment: @dermen, sorry for any confusion... Was messing with it in an attempt to better understand it and forgot to remove the "A". I fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I am new to this website and I am still learning how to post questions. Fixed the errors. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: What intrigues me is why you'd want to do it this way in the first place

Comment: @OldBill, Studying for a computer science 101 test and this was a practice problem.. Teacher is not available so I posted here

Comment: also, the `input(...` call is immaterial. you should remove everything except that essential to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are in a stage where you want to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

For questions on StackOverflow, you want to provide a minimal reproducible example. What does that mean in your case?

1. "repoducible" means that you should not depend on user input. Replace user input by hardcoded values.
2. "minimal" means that you don't call the function twice. Once is enough.

For that reason, I'll not walk you through your original program, but through this one instead:

```py
def reverse(s):
    new = ""
    for i in s:
        print(new)
        new = i + new
    return new

print(reverse("abcdef"))
```

I'll use a free program called [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows). You set a breakpoint where you want to understand how things work. Since you don't understand the `reverse()` method, put it right at the beginning of that method. You do that by clicking between the line number and the text:

[image: Breakpoint in Pycharm]

Even if your code has no bug, go to the Run/Debug menu:

[image: Debug in Pycharm]

Execution will stop at the breakpoint and you'll now be able to see all the variables and step through your code line by line.

[image: Watch and step in Pycharm]

Look at all the variables after each single line. Compare the values to what you *think* the values should be. If there is a mismatch, it's likely a misunderstanding on your side, not by Python. Do that a few times and it'll be obvious why and how the string is reversed.

Comment: Yes I am currently at that stage. Your breakdown is very simple and easy to understand. Once again all feedback (positive or negative) is welcome as there is always something to learn from either. Thank you!

Comment: On the answers that helped you, you can click the "arrow up" (or upvote) icon. An answer which you considered has solved you issue should be marked using the checkmark icon. That way other people know this issue has been resolved and they no longer need to think about it and write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let analysis it:
Iteration 1:
new = 'A', i = g

Perform new = i + new : new = gA

Iteration 2:
new = gA, i = o

Perform new = i + new: new = ogA
.
.
.

This happens because we add new i before we add the existing string from previous iteration.

Comment: This made a lot of sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Just to let you know, someone pointed out that new = "A" when it should have been blank. I edited the question but the explanation still made a lot of sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

the key is in "new = i + new" note that new is the previous iteration character and is in the right side of the current character, this cause the string to reverse